# Authentication in UWP Application

Tags: azure, uwp

We are planning to implement Windows 10 UWP Application. We would like to authenticate user while accessing API Services hosted in Cloud.

Previously, we used the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` NuGet package for authenticating in windows store 8.1. How do we authenticate user in Windows UWP Applications? I think AAD code for Windows Store and Windows Phone is different, how can we leverage AAD library for Windows 10 UWP applications. I have heard of Token Broker Authentication Architecture. Will this work for Azure Active Directory in addition to Facebook, etc.?

Please let me know if there is a workaround for AAD library to work in both Phone and Store (i.e. Universal App).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an Native App that wants to access an API on Azure and authenticate with oAuth you need to use "OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow" as describe on https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code/.

This requires that you both your native app and api in the Azure Directory.

In https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-windowsstore/ a sample is given of a UWP App that accesses the graph.microsoft.com API, but you can replace this by your own API.

Sander,

If this answers your question please tag is such so we can help others.

Comment: my UWP app does not work with AAD, I can signin using browser and endpoint like this [link](https://contoso.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback) but when I try to signin using UWP app, I got resource cannot be found error after bring prompted a window and after I enter my email address and hit enter. Does that mean I haven't setup my native app in Azure AD as well? and I've only setup the Azure Mobile App endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain the steps.
You can still use [Active Directory Authentication Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory)
in the UWP Apps.

To do it you have to add NuGet package (I pasted the link above). Once you do it there are few steps to implement authentication in your app:

1) Store information needed for the authentication (for instance in the App.xaml.cs constructor):

```
var localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
localSettings.Values["ida:AADInstance"] = "https://login.windows.net/{0}";
localSettings.Values["ida:Tenant"] = "<<Name of your tenant here>>";
localSettings.Values["ida:ClientId"] = "<<Client ID Here>>";
localSettings.Values["ida:RedirectUri"] = "<<Redirect URI here>>";
localSettings.Values["ApiBaseAddress"] = "<<ID of Api Resource here>>";
localSettings.Values["ServiceAddress"] = "<<Address of your Api here>>";
```

Now write the code for authentication (this is helper class):

```
class ADContextHelper
{
    ApplicationDataContainer _localSettings;
    AuthenticationContext _authContext;
    string _aadInstance;
    string _tenant;
    string _clientId;
    Uri _redirectUri;
    string _authority;
    string _apiResourceId;
    string _apiBaseAddress;

    public ADContext()
    {
        _localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        configureSettings();
        _authContext = new AuthenticationContext(_authority);
    }

    private void configureSettings()
    {
        _aadInstance = _localSettings.Values["ida:AADInstance"].ToString();
        _tenant = _localSettings.Values["ida:Tenant"].ToString();
        _clientId = _localSettings.Values["ida:ClientId"].ToString();
        _redirectUri = new Uri(_localSettings.Values["ida:RedirectUri"].ToString());
        _authority = String.Format(_aadInstance, _tenant);
        _apiResourceId = _localSettings.Values["ApiResourceId"].ToString();
        _apiBaseAddress = _localSettings.Values["ApiBaseAddress"].ToString();
    }

    public async Task<string> Authenticate()
    {
        AuthenticationResult authResult = await _authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(_apiResourceId, _clientId, _redirectUri);
       //Here you retrieve the token:
        var token = authResult.AccessToken;
        return token;
    }
}
```

At the end I also include code for logout - maybe you will want to include it:

```
public async Task<bool> Logout()
  {
     string requestUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + _tenant + "/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=" + _redirectUri;
     var client = new HttpClient();
     var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
     var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    }
```

I hope this will help you.